# Force a property to be mapped first with AutoMapper 11+

Tags: automapper, automapper-11

I have a couple of objects in a project which is currently using AutoMapper 10 where the I need one particular property to be mapped before all the others.  In AM10 this was easy by setting the target properties mapping order to some low value, then everything else to a higher one using `ForAllOtherMembers`:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
  .ForMember(d => d.MapMeFirst, opt => opt.SetMappingOrder(int.MinValue))
  .ForAllOtherMembers(c => c.SetMappingOrder(0));
);
```

But with AM11, `ForAllOtherMembers` has been removed.  No matter what I set the mapping order of `MapMeFirst` to, it makes no difference unless I also set the mapping order for every other property, which now has to be done explicitly without `ForAllOtherMembers`.

Is there anyway of achieving this another way?

Comment: Just use `BeforeMap`.

Comment: That will result though in `MapMeFirst` being mapped twice unless its explicitly excluded from AM with `opt.Ignore`.   Just wonder what the point of `SetMappingOrder` is if it has to be explicitly set on every member to actually have a defined effect.

Comment: The default is null and null comes first.